# Pure PHP implementation of SQLite?

Tags: php, sqlite

Is there a pure PHP implementation of SQLite that will run on PHP 5.1.6?  I am working on an application that would benefit from being able to store data in a relational database, but the server that it has to run on is stuck with PHP 5.1.6 and has been configured "'--without-sqlite"

I have no control over this server; cannot recompile, upgrade or otherwise modify PHP aside from using .htaccess files.  Hosting externally is also not an option, unfortunately.  MySQL may be possible but would be a nightmare trying to get their IT to create a database for me.  (It took them 6 weeks to get .htaccess files enabled because of red tape and other things)

Am I out of luck?  My fall back is to write everything to flat files but I really would rather not do that.

**EDIT:** Fixed typo. PHP does not have the SQLite extension and was configured "'--without-sqlite" according to the output of phpinfo()

Comment: Its not an answer, its just a comment: If you must use such an old PHP version (5.2 comes in end 2006) and then even without SQLite (that is usually enabled by default) you should consider to leave this hoster.

Comment: @John Kramlich: sqlite (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) has been built in since 5.1.  Are you able to get a phpinfo dump and see?  Or run this simple script: `echo (int) extension_loaded('sqlite');`

Comment: I agree.  However my hand is forced in this regard. The company mandates that the project be hosted internally and nothing I say or do will change this.  I have told them they are using extremely out of date versions of all of their server software and the ramifications of this decision.  I have provided them information on how to upgrade.  It is 100% out of my hands.

Comment: @John Kramlich: at this rate, you'd be better off just installing apache2, php, and maybe mysql on your personal machine and just set up a redirect on their host to your's...  they did say internal, but not exactly _where_ internally, right...?

Comment: Did you try the pdo sqlite http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php ?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer : That would work until they had 5000 requests at once and he can't open anything on his personal machine.  But if he did go your router, I'd go even more ridiculous and build out a web service that the outdated php can make to his personal machine to get data out of sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could easily [download and install sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) in your userspace, whether on windows or on a linux remote shell doesn t usually matter unless your host is unusually restrictive, if that is the case you should change service provider.

Once sqlite is installed, you can one of the available [pear extensions](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_sqlite/redirected) or [pecl extension](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to allow easy access through php.

- [Tutorial and code examples for the pear solution here](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Database-Articles/PEARSQLite-The-Lightweight-Alternative/).